# Was someone banned?

Tags: discussion, users

I saw this today morning:

[image]

Do we know who and why?

AFAIK, 250+ users have been affected.

Here's a snapshot of the most affected.
[image]

Related: [Massive user removal in one night?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328642)

Comment: I lost 400 points on VP as well, would like to know who was banned / closed their account ^^'

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, information about suspensions/account removals is private information and can not be disclosed by CMs or moderators unless the party in question chooses to reveal it.

I can say that it would be an account removal rather than a suspension though.  A suspension would not impact the reputations of users, only an account removal.  (If anyone else notices a name missing from the user list, they are welcome to post it though.)

It's a bit interesting that it impacted so many reputations as well, they used to freeze reputation changes after a while (something like 90 days I think it was) to avoid this kind of recalc on a removal, but I guess they decided to reverse course on that, or maybe just extended it.

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328642/massive-user-removal-in-one-night) meta post covers more (not much more) from SE on the subject.